# How to restrict my android app in rooted device which contain magisk app?

Tags: java, android, root, rooted-device

I am working on an android app. I want to save my app from rooted devices. I am successfully restricting my app with rooted devices, but one rooted device has magisk app, so with the help of this magis app, user is able to open my app in rooted device also. can any body help me in this? Thanks in advance.

my code is

private static boolean checkRootMethod1() {
        String buildTags = Build.TAGS;
        return buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys");
    }

```
private static boolean checkRootMethod2() {
    String[] paths = {"/system/apn/which sup/Superuser.apk", "/sbin/su", "/system/bin/su", "/system/xbin/su",
            "/data/local/xbin/su", "/data/local/bin/su", "/system/sd/xbin/su", "/system/bin/.ext/.su",
            "/system/bin/failsafe/su", "/data/local/su", "/system/xbin/mu", "/su/bin/su", "/system/usr/we-need-root/su-backup"};
    for (String path : paths) {
        if (new File(path).exists()) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean checkRootMethod3() {
    File file = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    return file != null && file.canWrite();
}

private static boolean checkRootMethod4() {
    File file = new File("/system/bin/");
    return file != null && file.canWrite();
}

private static  boolean checkRootMethod5() {
    return new File("/system/app/Superuser.apk").exists();
}
```

Comment: That's basically like asking if we are living in the Matrix. You may find a way to detect that your app runs on a rooted device, but the system may lie to your app tomorrow.

Comment: So what should exactly i need to do?

Comment: Have a look at [SafetyNet](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/index.html). Btw I actually didn't use them yet. Specifically [here](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation.html) I read "Purely to check whether the device is rooted, as the API is designed to check the overall integrity of the device.". Anyway, as Johannes says, maybe it could be circumvented.

Comment: @shadowsheep thanks for reply, let me check. I'll get back to you

Answer (score 1):

After couple of days, I got the solution. [RootDevice](https://github.com/scottyab/rootbeer) is the library which will check for all kind of root device check. Like:

- CheckRootManagementApps
- CheckPotentiallyDangerousApps
- CheckRootCloakingApps
- CheckTestKeys
- checkForDangerousProps
- checkForBusyBoxBinary
- checkForSuBinary
- checkSuExists
- checkForRWSystem

Comment: Good to know! Let's know your feedback after some time of usage!

Comment: Yehh sure @shadowsheep. Let cyber security test the build then I'll let you know

Comment: Hello @AmitJayaswal, it's interesting to see you managed to detect root even Magisk Hide in placed. Im currently looking into a solution as well, however from what I understand Magisk is a “systemless” root method, which is installed by modifying the boot image file boot.img. May I know which methods (in your solution mentioned) was used detect the root? Thank you

Comment: RootBeer rootBeer = new RootBeer(this);
        if (rootBeer.isRooted()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.root_device_error),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
Hi @Tommy I hope you will get the method.

Comment: Will try and response back, might take awhile. Im on RN platform. Thanks for the response too!

Comment: @TommyLeong Magisk Hide is able to bypass the rootbeer checks. There is another way to defeat Magisk Hide (see https://twitter.com/topjohnwu/status/1298468244596985856 for example), but it may not work in the future.

Answer (score 1):

check for magisk hide options to.
Magisk Hide lets you use apps without letting it know that it is the rooted device